# Fastest way of pulling a user's group (for millions of rows)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my current database structure:

```
- usersGroups
    - group1
        - user1: true
        - user2: true
        - user3: true

- users
    - user1
        - name: 'Bob'
        - group: group1
    - user2
        - name: 'Carl'
        - group: group2
    - user3
        - name: 'Peter'
        - group: group3
```

In order to determine the names of users that belong to `group1`, I currently perform this request:

```
const groupUserSnap = firebase.database().ref('usersGroups/group1').once('value');

let userPromises = [];
groupUserSnap.forEach((snap) => {
    userPromises.push(
        firebase.database().ref(`users/${snap.key}`).once('value')
    );
});

// Wait until we have resolved promises for each user key
const userSnaps = await Promise.all(userPromises);

userSnaps.forEach((userSnap) => {
    const user = userSnap.val();
    console.log(`User's name is ${user.name}`);
});
```

This query fetches all the keys of the users that belong to the relevant group, and then loops through each one to pull the full user values.

Recently, we have added the `group` key to each user as well (as shown in structure above) so that we can easily identify the group a user belongs to without having to query `userGroups`.

Now that the `group` key is present under the `user`, we can perform this query instead to retrieve users belonging to a group:

```
firebase.database().ref('users').orderByChild('group').equalTo('group1').once('child_added');
```

My question is, does this query now make the `usersGroups` data redundant, or should I continue to retrieve a groups' users as I did in the previous example, for speed purposes?

Comment: I now little of Firebase, I assume it has some similarities with other databases.
What does user3: true means in the above? Does that mean, user3 belongs to the group?

Can you create an index for user.group? In that way you can quickly get all groups without having to maintain the seperate userGroups collection.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it would be better to structure the data like this:

```
- users
    - user1
        - name: 'Bob'
        - group: 1
    - user2
        - name: 'Carl'
        - group: 2
    - user3
        - name: 'Peter'
        - group: 3
```

Don't forget to update your firebase database rules to something like this:

```
"users": {
      ".indexOn": ["group"]
    }
```

Then you will be able to filter/sort the data like this:

```
let groupNum = 1  // the group's number being filtered
firebase.database().ref('users')
.orderByChild('group')
.equalTo(groupNum)
.once('value', (snapshot) => {
  let filteredUsers = []
  snapshot.forEach((user) => {
    filteredUsers.push({
      _key: user.key,
      ...user.val() //this will add all the user's value
    })
  })
  console.log(filteredUsers) // will show [{_key: 'user1', name: 'Bob', group: 1}]
})
```

Easier to filter data, less code and no need to make an array of all the users in the group and then get their data since the group is now assigned and being filtered from the database itself.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include some explanation/reasoning as to why you think this solution is better.

Comment: Easier to filter data, less code and no need to make an array of all the users in the group and then get their data since the group is now assigned and being filtered from the database itself.

Comment: thanks! You should post that explanation as an edit to the answer, though (click the edit link underneath the answer) rather than as a comment. Comments on Stack Overflow are transient and not guaranteed to last forever.

Comment: I'm curious how this is different from what the OP posted since he already has a group field for each user?

Comment: Why type all that 'groupX' if he is only using numbers... Also he is just trying to filter the users by group, now if he needs the "usergroup" to more functions then he should read https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/structure-data#flatten_data_structures